# How to pass variables back from php by ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have script from login page which through ajax sends data into php, and php returns if successful or not, I just wonder how can I change my scripts so it would send back also 2 variables and receive it in my login js script so I can create cookies? here are my js and php scripts:

**js**:

```
$(document).on('pageinit',function(){
        $("#login").click(function(){

            username=$("#usr").val();
            password=$("#psw").val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://imes.***********.com/php/login_check.php",
                data: "name="+username+"&pwd="+password,
                success: function(html){
                    //in case of success
                    if(html=='true')
                    {
                        $("#login_message").html("Logged in, congratulation.");
                        $.mobile.changePage("http://imes.***********.com/userpanel.php");
                    }
                    //in case of error
                    else
                    {
                        $("#login_message").html("Wrong username or password");
                    }
                },
                beforeSend: function() { $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg(); }, //Show spinner
                complete: function() { $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg() } //Hide spinner
            });
            return false;
        });
```

**php**:

```
<?php
session_start();
    $username = $_POST['name'];
    $password = $_POST['pwd'];
    include('mysql_connection.php');
    mysql_select_db("jzperson_imesUsers", $con);

    $res1 = mysql_query(
     "SELECT * FROM temp_login WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'"
     );

    $num_row = mysql_num_rows($res1);
    if ($num_row == 1) {
        echo 'true';
    }
     else {
        echo 'false';
    }
?>
```

Comment: Make the cookies in PHP.

Comment: This is not related to your question, but you have a serious SQL injection vulnerability in your PHP script. You should escape your input parameters before building our SQL statement or even better use prepared statements.

Comment: oh yeah I know about all those security issues, this is so far just to find out how to work with certain things. but thx...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use Json as response:

**PHP side**

```
...
$json = new Services_JSON();
echo $json->encode("{a:1,b:2}");
```

**JS**

```
...
 success:function(data){
            if(data)
            {
             console.log(data.a);
             console.log(data.b);
             }
  ....
```

You can encode any array in PHP and pass it as ajax callback.

Json class you can get [there](http://php.net/manual/en/json.installation.php)

Comment: how can I set the data on js side to be added into variables? usr = console.log(data.a); and psw = console.log(data.b);?

Comment: no, any value you added to json string (or array) u can extract from data like: data.a. for u: `usr = data.a;` ...

Answer (score 2):

You can use JSON to return values to your JS script. In your PHP code return something like:

```
{
    "result": true,
    "your_variable": "variable_value"
}
```

You can use [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) function. And then in JS parse it with [jQuery.parseJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a JSON formatted response to return values from PHP to JS (look at json_encode() PHP function : http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php ).

Or just set the value in the cookie from PHP ( http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php )